# Problem with non-explicit layout binding in OpenGL shader input parameters -- why?

Tags: opengl

The following works:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 uv;
layout(location = 3) in vec4 color;
```

While the following doesn't (the bindings get corrupted somehow and `color` ends up in place of `normal` according to RenderDoc):

```
in vec3 position;
in vec3 normal;
in vec2 uv;
in vec4 color;
```

The actual structure in code is this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    struct Vertex
    {
        public Vector3 Position;
        public Vector3 Normal;
        public Vector2 UV;
        public Vector4 Color;

        public Vertex(Vector3 position, Vector3 normal, Vector2 uv, Vector4 color) =>
            (Position, Normal, UV, Color) = (position, normal, uv, color);
    }
```

So from what I read, I shouldn't need explicit layout location in this case, and this is the first time that hasn't worked as expected. Could you tell me what I'm missing and why it doesn't work like this?

Comment: *"what I read, I shouldn't need explicit layout location in this case"* Where did you read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not specify the attributes indices through [layout qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)), the attribute indexes are not specified and can have any value. There is no guarantee of the order nor that the indices are 0, 1, 2 and 3.
You must get the attribute indexes with [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) after you link the program, or you must specify the attribute indexes with [`glBindAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml) before you link the program.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 7.3.1.1 Naming Active Resources](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=128&zoom=100,168,214)

> The order of the active resource list is implementation-dependent for all
> interfaces except for TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_VARYING.